# Converting Decimal in String Format to a Double Using Stacks

Tags: c++, list, type-conversion, stack

this project is currently due by tonight and I have tried my best on it so far. If I could get any guidance on to how I should continue working on it that would be greatly appreciated. I have this topic I am covering for a project: "Write a program that reads a string consisting of a positive integer or a positive decimal number and converts the number to the numeric format. If the string consists of a decimal number, the program must use a stack to convert the decimal number to the numeric format."

I am first of all, confused as to how a stack would help make a decimal in string format into a decimal in numeric format. How would that work internally in the program? Second of all, my code that I created is not working for some reason and I'm unsure as to of why.

I tried looking into questions that were asked on stack overflow and other websites but nothing could answer my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


template <class Type>
class stackADT
{
public:
    virtual void initializeStack() = 0;
    virtual bool isEmptyStack() const = 0;
    virtual bool isFullStack() const = 0;
    virtual void push(const Type& newItem) = 0;
    virtual Type top() const = 0;
    virtual void pop() = 0;
};

template <class Type>
class stackType: public stackADT<Type>
{
private:
    int maxStackSize;
    int stackTop;

public:
    Type *list;
    void initializeStack()
    {
        stackTop = 0;
        cout << "stackTop " << stackTop << endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<stackTop; i++)
        {
            cout << list[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    bool isEmptyStack() const
    {
        return(stackTop == 0);
    }

    bool isFullStack() const
    {
        return(stackTop == maxStackSize);
    }

    void push(const Type& newItem)
    {
        if (!isFullStack())
        {
            list[stackTop] = newItem;
            stackTop++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Cannot add to a full stack." << endl;
        }
        cout << "stacktop: " << stackTop << endl;

        system("pause");
    }

    Type top() const
    {
        assert(stackTop != 0); //if stack is empty, terminate the program.
        return list[stackTop - 1];
    }

    Type getList() const
    {
        assert(stackTop != 0); //if stack is empty, terminate the program.
        return *list;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (!isEmptyStack())
            stackTop--;
        else
            cout << "Cannot remove from an empty stack." << endl;

        cout << "pop: " << stackTop << endl;
    }

    stackType(int stackSize = 100)
    {
        if (stackSize <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Size of the array to hold the stack must be positive." << endl;
            cout << "Creating an array of size 100." << endl;
            maxStackSize = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            maxStackSize = stackSize;
            // cout << "maxStackSize "  << maxStackSize << endl;
        }

        stackTop = 0;
        list = new Type[maxStackSize];
    }

    stackType(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
    {
        list = NULL;
        copyStack(otherStack);
    }

    ~stackType()
    {
        delete [] list;
    }

    const stackType<Type>& operator=(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
    {
        if (this != &otherStack)
        {
            copyStack(otherStack);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const stackType<Type>& otherStack) const
    {
        if (this == &otherStack)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (stackTop != otherStack.stackTop)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i] != otherStack.list[i])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void copyStack(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
    {
        delete [] list;
        maxStackSize = otherStack.maxStackSize;
        stackTop = otherStack.stackTop;

        list = new Type[maxStackSize];

        //copy otherStack into this stack.
        for (int j = 0; j < stackTop; j++)
        {
            list[j] = otherStack.list[j];
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s;
    char c;
    bool found;
    int b = 0;

    string j = "";
    stackType<double> stack;

    cout<<"Would you like to convert an integer(i) or a decimal(d)?"<<endl;
    cin>>c;

    switch (c) {
        case 'i' :
        case 'I' : {
            cout << "Please enter your integer in string format: ";
            cin >> s;

            b = atoi(s.c_str());
            break;
        }
        case 'd' :

        case 'D' : {

            cout << "Please enter your decimal in string format: ";
            cin >> s;

            found = false;

            int q = 0;

            while(found == false) {

                if(s[q] == '.') {
                    found = true;

                }
                else {
                    q++;
                }

            }


            for (int i = 0; i <q; i++) {
                char p = s[i];



                j += p;

                for (int m = 0; m<q-i; m++) {

                    j += '0';

                }
                double k = stof(j);
                stack.push(k);
                j.clear();

            }

            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout <<"Wrong input. Please enter i or d for integer or decimal: ";
             cin>>c;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Here is your string in integer or decimal format: ";
    double t = 0;

    if(c == 'i') {

        cout << b;

    }
    else if(c == 'd') {

        for(int i = 0; i < stack.top(); i++){

            t += stack.list[i];

        }

        cout << t;



    }



    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be the number printed out correctly as to when I entered it but the output is :

Would you like to convert an integer(i) or a decimal(d)?
d
Please enter your decimal in string format: 1025.56
stacktop: 1
sh: pause: command not found
stacktop: 2
sh: pause: command not found
stacktop: 3
sh: pause: command not found
stacktop: 4
sh: pause: command not found
Here is your string in integer or decimal format: 9.74742e+232Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: *"I am first of all, confused as to how a stack would help make a decimal in string format into a decimal in numeric format."* So am I, what's "numeric format" supposed to mean? C++ doesn't have any built-in decimal class IIRC.

Comment: Double or float

Comment: Implement your code however you like, every c++ program uses a stack ...

Comment: I could only hazard a guess here. First you can use `std::stack` instead of implementing your own if you are allowed to do so. Push all the digits into the stack and pop them out one by one and add to the final output . You have to divide by `10` as you keep finding elements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Wander3r . That got me to thinking of how I could redo my code and make it better and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the input string be 2345.6789. Since it is a string, its individual characters are stored in the consecutive locations in memory. Now, let's access them sequentially, and execute the following algorithm.

First, evaluate the integer part

```
int Acc = 0;
Loop 1: Repeat until Input == Decimal point

Input = '2'; Acc = 10 * Acc + (Input - '0') = 10 x 0 + 2 = 2
Input = '3'; Acc = 10 * Acc + (Input - '0') = 10 x 2 + 3 = 23
Input = '4'; Acc = 10 * Acc + (Input - '0') = 10 x 23 + 4 = 234
Input = '5'; Acc = 10 * Acc + (Input - '0') = 10 x 234 + 5 = 2345
Input = '.' (Decimal point); exit Loop1
```

Next, fill the stack with digits in the fractional part.

```
auto stack = std::stack<int>
Loop2: Repeat until Input == End of string

Input = '6'; stack.push (Input - '0');
Input = '7'; stack.push (Input - '0');
Input = '8'; stack.push (Input - '0');
Input = '9'; stack.push (Input - '0');
Input = End of string; exit Loop2
```

Next, pop digits from the stack, and evaluate the fractional part.

```
double Acc2 = 0;
Loop 3: repeat until stack.empty()

Acc2 = (Acc2 + stack.top()) / 10 = (0 + 9) / 10 = 0.9; stack.pop();
Acc2 = (Acc2 + stack.top()) / 10 = (0.9 + 8) / 10 = 0.89; stack.pop();
Acc2 = (Acc2 + stack.top()) / 10 = (0.89 + 7) / 10 = 0.789; stack.pop();
Acc2 = (Acc2 + stack.top()) / 10 = (0.789 + 6) / 10 = 0.6789; stack.pop();
```

Finally, add the integer part to the fractional part.

```
Result = Acc + Acc2
```

This is a purely academic problem. Convey my regards to your teacher.

Comment: Very well done, good kind sir. I appreciate your help from the depths of my heart. :)